# How to split huge file into small chunks and load parallelly into Dynamodb using Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

How to split huge file (suppose 5 million records) into small chunks (suppose each chunk may have 100k records) and load parallelly into Dynamodb using Boto3.

Is this possible using boto3, currently i've some requirement like this. Any guidance or sample code help a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Boto3 will just be performing the `put` operations to load the data. You need to look outside Boto3 for some method of splitting your files and running multiple load processes in paralle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
tot_lines = 100000

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    fout = open('out0.txt','wb')
    for c,i in enumerate(f):
      fout.write(i)
      if (c+1)%tot_lines == 0:
        fout.close()
        fout = open('out%d.txt'%(c/tot_lines+1),'wb')
    fout.close()
```

This will create `n` number of files where each file will have `100k` records. You can then load them the way you want.